# Get edge list that includes alter's alters

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph, data-manipulation, edge-list

I need a data frame that includes three columns: i, j (alter), and k (j's alter). I have an adjacency matrix (sample below). From there I can get a graph object and extract the edge list. How can I manipulate the data to get an output like the WANT data frame below?

HAVE (matrix & edgelist):

```
      1   2   3   4   5   

 1    0   0   0   1   0  
 2    0   0   1   1   1   
 3    0   0   0   0   0   
 4    1   1   0   0   1   
 5    1   1   0   1   0    


g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat)

get.edgelist(g)


i   j

1   4
2   3
2   4
2   5
4   1
4   2
4   5
5   1
5   2
5   4
```

WANT (ijk edge list):

```
i j k
1 4 2
1 4 5
2 4 1
2 4 5
4 2 3
4 5 1
4 5 2
5 1 4 
5 2 3
5 2 4
5 4 1
5 4 2
```

the ijk edge list should so all possible triples with ij, excluding self loops(ex: 1 4 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Data:***

```r
as.matrix(read.table(text = "0   0   0   1   0  
                             0   0   1   1   1   
                             0   0   0   0   0   
                             1   1   0   0   1   
                             1   1   0   1   0",
                     header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)) -> m1

dimnames(m1) <- list(1:5, 1:5)
```

***Libraries:***

```r
library(igraph) 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
```

***Solution:***

```r
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m1)
e1 <- get.edgelist(g1) %>% as.data.frame %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)

e1 %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  nest(V2) %>% 
  right_join(e1,.,by = c("V2"="V1")) %>%  
  unnest %>% 
  filter(V1 != V21) %>% 
  set_colnames(c("i", "j", "k"))
```

***Output:***

```r
#>    i j k
#> 1  1 4 2
#> 2  1 4 5
#> 3  2 4 1
#> 4  2 4 5
#> 5  2 5 1
#> 6  2 5 4
#> 7  4 2 3
#> 8  4 2 5
#> 9  4 5 1
#> 10 4 5 2
#> 11 5 1 4
#> 12 5 2 3
#> 13 5 2 4
#> 14 5 4 1
#> 15 5 4 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I was actually able to get a way to do it using igraph and dplyr:

```
# make graph of matrix
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat)


# put edgelist into two objects, one where columns are "i, j" and the other "j, k"
df1 <- get.edgelist(g) %>%
       as.data.frame() %>%
       select(i = V1, j = V2)

df2 <- get.edgelist(g) %>%
       as.data.frame() %>%
       select(j = V1, k = V2)

# combine the dataframes, filter out rows where i and k are the same observation
df_combn <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("j" = "j")) %>%
            mutate_all(as.character) %>%
            filter(., !(i == k))
```

Comment: Nice one. The only reason I used `nest` was to show you that it's possible to get the output in a cleaner format. (disclaimer: I actually saw your `inner_join` and switched to `right_join`) Cheers. +1